# No jquery event.target on iOS

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I have a list built with jQuery that displays just fine on any device I have tried it on, I have been able to click on the list and trigger the targets specific event everywhere, even in Chrome Developer Tools with "Touch" enabled.

My list looks like this.

```
<ul class="items"></ul>
```

Then I build it with a bunch of li with jquery and it displays just fine. However, on the iOS Simulator and my iPhone I can't get the event target when tapping it, but it is displayed on the screen, I can see it and I can scroll its parent and stuff, but not target these list items. I have tried with this code:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
  console.log(e.target.classList);
});
```

This works just fine and logs every element on the entire page except this list, have anyone here experienced this? I have tried to put it relative with an absurd z-index, but nothing works.

Comment: Is `e` defined? What's does that object contain?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't bind click event to all element of your list ? it's easier.

```
$('.items').each(function(){
$(this).click(myFunctionWhenClicked)
})

function myFunctionWhenClicked(e){
    // Here e is the event 
    // and 'this' is the element
}
```